# pysimplegui status bar acting strange

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

**my problem**:

i have been trying to make a python clone of notepad to learn how pysimplegui works. so i started with following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQY641uynKo) and then changed some code around to look more like notepad. but when i added a status bar i noticed it did not act the way i wanted instead of it being a small strip at the bottom of the window it has a big border going under it and when i resize the window the status bar doesn't really move vertically.

**code and images**:

[here](https://pastebin.com/8FhVumiH) is the code for the gui:

```
#~~~~imports~~~~
import PySimpleGUI as sg
 
import pathlib
 
WIN_W = 90
WIN_H = 25
 
'''
sg.ChangeLookAndFeel('SystemDefault')
'''
#~~~~layout~~~~
#/settings
menu_def = [['File', ['New    Ctrl+N', 'Open...    Ctrl+O', 'Save    Ctrl+S','Save As...', '---', 'Page Setup...', 'Print...    Ctrl+P', '---', 'Exit'  ]],      
                ['Edit', ['Undo    Ctrl+Z', '---', 'cut    Ctrl+X', 'copy    Ctrl+C', 'Paste    Ctrl+V', 'delete    Del', '---', 'find...    Ctrl+F', 'Find Next    F3', 'Replace...    Ctrl+H', 'Go To...    Ctrl+G', '---', 'Select All    Ctrl+A', 'Time/Date    F5'], ],
                ['format', ['Word Wrap', 'font...'], ],
                ['view', ['Status Bar'], ],      
                ['Help', ['View Help', '---', 'About memopad'], ], ]
 
Ln_numb = 1
Col_numb = 1
#/the layout
layout = [[sg.Menu(menu_def)],
          [sg.Multiline(font=('Consolas', 12), size=(WIN_W, WIN_H-1), key='_BODY_')],
          [sg.StatusBar( text=f'| Ln{Ln_numb},Col{Col_numb}', size=(WIN_W,1), pad=(0,0), text_color='black', background_color='white', relief=sg.RELIEF_FLAT, justification='right', visible=False, key='status_bar' )]
          ]
 
#/window
window = sg.Window('untitled - notepad', icon=['D:/python/memopad/Notepad.ICO'], border_depth=0, layout=layout, element_padding=(0, 0), margins=(0, 0), resizable=True, return_keyboard_events=True, finalize=True)
window['_BODY_'].expand(expand_x=True, expand_y=True)
window['status_bar'].expand(expand_x=True, expand_y=True)
window['status_bar'].update(visible=False)
#~~~~event loop~~~~
status_bar_switch = True
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (None, 'Exit'):
        break
 
    if event in ('Status Bar'):
        if status_bar_switch:
            window['status_bar'].update(visible=True)
            status_bar_switch = False
        else:
            window['status_bar'].update(visible=False)
            status_bar_switch = True
```

[this is a image of my notepad clone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIlj9.png)

looks fine right?

[well this is what it look like when streched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0q4t.png)

[this is Microsofts notepad when maximized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGw5M.png)

[and this is my clone when maximized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXtxo.png)

**what i tried**:

1. I added pad(0,0) to the status bar element
2. I adding expand_row=True to the .expand line of code but noticed no difference
3. I tried to change the size of the element
4. I tried to google for an answer
5. I looked at the [pysimplegui docs](http://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io) website

Answer (score 1):

this was solved by pysimplegui over on [github](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/3085)